# Graphql belongs to relationship

Tags: graphql

So I am learning GraphQL and I am trying to understand when building the schema how I do relationships. So I have an Apps table with a field show that has a foreign key setup to the Show table. How do I do this in graphql schema? This is what I have at this point

```
const schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    app: App
  }
  type App {
    id: Int
    show: Int
    name: String
    url: String
    author: String
    price: Float
    image: String
  }
  type Show {
    id: Int
    name: String
    airDate: String
  }
`);
```

Maybe I need something to tell it of the relationship? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'd generally set up the GraphQL schema to refer to the other object and not have its ID at all in the referrer:

```
type App {
  id: Int
  show: Show
  ...
}
type Show {
  id: Int
  name: String
  ...
}
```

That way a query doesn't have to know that there's an intermediate database lookup involved

```
query GetApp {
  app {
    name
    url
    show { name }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is excellent. Show if I wanted to setup fake data for this to work, how would that look?